# random text (Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller that shows a random question. In this class I have a button; when you click on this button it goes to another view and shows the correct answer.

I can show my random question but how can I set my correct answer in another view? (based on my question)

My code for random question is:

```
{
  NSString *one = @"Question 1?";
  NSString *two = @"Question 2?";
  NSString *three = @"Question 3?";
  NSString *four = @"Question 4?";
  NSString *five = @"Question 5?";
  NSString *six = @"Question 6?";

  NSArray *answerComments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:one, two, three, four, five, six, nil];
  int rand = arc4random()%6;

  NSString *answer = [answerComments objectAtIndex:rand];

  [question setText:(answer)];
  [question setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 295, 200, 80)];
  question.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
  question.numberOfLines = 0;
}

- (IBAction)answer:(id)sender {
  AnswerViewController *b = [[AnswerViewController alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
}
```

In my next view that shows the correct answer I have `UILabel *correctAnswer`

```
NSString *one = @"answer 1";
NSString *two = @"answer 2";
NSString *three = @"answer 3";
NSString *four = @"answer 4";
NSString *five = @"answer 5";
NSString *six = @"answer 6";
```

Comment: just pass index of the chosen question into AnswerViewController via property

Comment: @benzado my question is how can I set correct answer to the question since I used random question

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you're putting model stuff into your controllers.

What you'd properly do is have a model object that picks a question and answer. The question controller would fetch the question and push it to a view. The answer controller would fetch the answer and push it to a view.

Depending on where you stand on singletons, either the model would be one or you'd instantiate a suitable model and probably push the relevant QuestionAnswer object onward.

Comment: do you know any sample or tutorial?

Comment: Certainly the main problem is that you have no proper separation between your model and controller. But, if you create proper data structure for questions and answer to them, it would really simplify your task. Go upon creating NSDictionary of question and answer or two different array one for question and another for answer as property. The question at certain index should be the answer at the same index in answer array.